# Printing tree by levels?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Reading the first suggested algorithm on: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal :

```
/*Function to print level order traversal of tree*/
printLevelorder(tree)
for d = 1 to height(tree)
   printGivenLevel(tree, d);

/*Function to print all nodes at a given level*/
printGivenLevel(tree, level)
if tree is NULL then return;
if level is 1, then
    print(tree->data);
else if level greater than 1, then
    printGivenLevel(tree->left, level-1);
    printGivenLevel(tree->right, level-1);
```

they mentioned that time complexity is `O(N^2)` in worst case but why?

We scan each node exactly once which means complexity is O(N) always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scan each node `h(branch)-h(node) + 1` times.

See this example:

```
   A
    \
     B
      \
       C
        \
         D
```

At printGivenLevel(tree, 1), you scan only A, and finish.
At printGivenLevel(tree, 2), you scan A and B, and finish
At printGivenLevel(tree, 3), you scan A, B  and C, and finish
At printGivenLevel(tree, 4), you scan A, B, C and D, and finish

Summing these all together gives you [sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), which is `O(n^2)`